# tableau server security issues in version 9

Tags: tableau-api

I am currently using tableau 9 version for my development purpose, same version tableau server as well. Currently I am using ldap authentication for the users to be added. In Tableau Server, I have given project level settings to restrict other department people. I have given interactor permissions for one of the user. But that user is able to access the whole site information(other projects as well) like a site admin rights.

Second issue I found that as, if we share the url with some other business unit member, they are able to access the url without any trouble (they are not added as ldap user in tableau site).

Please let me know if you face similar issues using tableau server ldap authentication.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you split this into two separate questions. That will simplify giving answers and for future site visitors here.

Comment: Second issue i got the answer, that is through guest access. Thanks! I am looking for the first question answer only.